# Finding probability of 2 cards summing to an odd number

Tags: probability

10 cards numbered from 1 to 10 are contained. Find the probability that the sum of 2 cards drawn is odd if

a.) The two cards are drawn together
b.) The two cards are drawn one after the other without replacement
c.) The two cards are drawn one after the other with replacement

So I wrote out the sample space. There are 45 possible sums when drawing two cards and 25 of those possibilities are odd.

I am confused by the difference between a and b. Isn't that doing the same thing basically?

Is a just 25/45?

Comment: Yes, nice observation.  Another way to see that $\frac{25}{45} = \frac{5}{9}$ is the right answer is to notice that, after the first card is drawn, regardless of the outcome exactly $5$ of the remaining $9$ cards will make the sum odd.  Maybe you can use the same concept to solve part (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) there are C(10,2) = 45 ways of choosing a pair of cards. There are C(5,2) = 10 ways of selecting a pair of cards that are both even numbered cards, and the same for the case of both odd numbered cards. So there are: 45 - 10 - 10 = 25 ways of selecting a pair of cards in which one is odd and the other is even numbered. So the probability in this case is: 25/45 = 5/9.

For b) there are 9*10 = 90 ways to choose 2 cards one after another w/o replacement. There are 5 ways to pick an odd card, followed by 5 ways to pick an even card and vice versa. So there are 2*5*5 = 50 ways to pick 2 cards one after another such that the sum is odd. So the probability is: 50/90 = 5/9.

For c) there are still 10*10 = 100 ways of choosing 2 cards one after another with replacement. There are 2*5*5 = 50 ways of choosing 2 cards one after another with replacement that the sum is odd. So the probability is : 50/100 = 1/2.

Comment: Is there a way to express part b with the format nCr?

Comment: @rojas777:sure is. 9*10 = C(2,1)*C(10,2), and 2*5*5 = C(2,1)*C(5,1)*C(5,1)